# I'd like to remove a constant from a URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with URL's like this:

```
http://website.com/browse/wedding-service-providers/bridal-wear-and-accessories/
```

I'd like to remove

```
/browse/wedding-service-providers
```

from the url each time so that the resulting URL is

```
http://website.com/bridal-wear-and-accessories/
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the "bridal-wear-and-accessories" part of the url is NOT a constant and will change... so it might be http://website.com/browse/wedding-service-providers/bob-and-margaret...

Answer (score 0):

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /



    RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*)$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]


Then url like
http://website.com/bridal-wear-and-accessories-c-3/
in this url 3 is the id of category
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep... One thing I should have mentioned tho, is that "/bridal-wear-and-accessories/" is not a constant.. That will change from category to category.

Comment: no doesn't seem to have any effect... thanks anyways. I'll see if I can find another solution other than htaccess. Thanks!